# How to display contents of a listbox as soon as an item is added?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, listbox-control

I have an application where i need to display a list of string outputs from a function in a System.Web.UI.ListBox. To get one string output (executing the function) it takes some time .I am adding the string output to the listbox after it is produced.Whats is my problem is that the application waits the entire time (till all items are calculated and added to listbox) and finally displays the entire listbox in one go (after waiting for quite a while due to the time required for generating large number of  output string). Kindly someone help me to show the listox item on the page as soon as it is added.Thank you.

```
public void add_to_list_box()
{
   int b; 
   for (b = 0; b <= 20; b++) 
   {
      string message = demo(b);
      ListBox1.Items.Add(message);
   }
   Button2.Text = "completed"; 
}
```

Comment: Please show us what and how you have done so far?

Comment: public void add_to_list_box()
        {
            int b;
            
            for (b = 0; b <= 20; b++)
            {
                string message = demo(b);
               ListBox1.Items.Add(message);
                            }

            Button2.Text = "completed";
            }

Comment: demo(b) takes time to execute and generate the output string. i want to display the listbox(with whatever items have been populated till now ) as son as one more item is added.

Comment: its waiting for the entire for loop to execute add all items and display the listbox items (all) in one go. I want it to be displayed like step by step. Can reloading page anyway help ?

Comment: in other words , i want to display a current snapshot of the listbox may be after a fixed interval of 2 seconds or so .

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that your code that is filling the ListBox is running on the web server, and it generates html / css / etc. After whole page is generated, it's send to the client. In your case client is Web browser, and after page is generated, send to the client only then is displayed.

In order to achieve your that instant display you have to use [Ajax](http://www.asp.net/ajax)

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax. In the url put the add_to_list_box() function, and then in the success part of the Ajax, do this:

```
Button2.Text = "completed";
```